# Python combine element of one list to another

Tags: python, string, list

I have an input which consists of a long string followed by a few numbers. The columns are all space limited. I have to drop "ABC" from each line in the final output (but I'm using it as a limiter to extract the first part of the first column). I also need to use X as a delimiter. I've been playing around with basic python commands to achieve this

Note: The actual file consists of thousands of such rows.

```
xyz.ABC_hi1_X_hi2_X_hi3_X_hi4   3  4  6  7
pqrst.ABC_me1_X_me2             2  5  7  8
```

I'm looking for an output like this

```
xyz.hi_1    3 4 6 7 
xyz.hi_2    3 4 6 7 
xyz.hi_3    3 4 6 7 
xyz.hi_4    3 4 6 7 
pqrst.me_1  2 5 7 8
pqrst.me_2  2 5 7 8
```

Snippet of what I have been testing so far (this is obviously not the final code). I'm looking for advice on how to approach this by making using of more savvy python commands.

```
with open("test", 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        col1 = line.split(' ')[0]
        split_col1 = col1.split('ABC_')
        to_append = split_col1[0]
        second_str = split_col[1]
        reg = second_str.split('_X_')
```

I'm having trouble combining to_append and each element returned in reg to produce the final output (shown in the second pic)

Comment: What's the question? Please read [ask]. `to_append` doesn't actually exist because the code never gets that far, so I'm not sure what you need help with. Do you understand why `col1('ABC_')` raises an error? Maybe you just made a typo there, but then your code has other obvious errors too.

Comment: You aren't doing any printing here.  Each line of input is going to produce multiple lines of output.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly The asterisk got inserted with "bold". I corrected it now.

Comment: @wjandrea I'm looking for guidance here on how to approach this problem. I corrected the typo you mentioned. Could you explain what the other errors are?

Comment: @TimRoberts This is just a snippet of what I tried. I am printing and testing the results on my side.

Comment: @user8217644 You can run the code yourself to see the problems. Firstly there's a NameError, secondly there's no output (since it's incomplete), which, on second thought, isn't an error per se. Now, we don't exactly do guidance or advice here; posts need to be specific questions. Please do read [ask]. See also ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341), though it's a little harsh. FWIW though, you could use Pandas if you're up for it; it makes dealing with large tabular data easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the line at the first space.  Split the suffix at the ABC string.  Now you can shop the rest into pieces and print your output:

```
with open("x.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        name,_,vals = line.rstrip().partition(' ')
        prefix,_,suffix = name.partition('ABC_')
        for parts in suffix.split('_X_'):
            print(prefix+parts[:-1]+'_'+parts[-1], vals)
```

Output:

```
xyz.hi_1   3  4  6  7
xyz.hi_2   3  4  6  7
xyz.hi_3   3  4  6  7
xyz.hi_4   3  4  6  7
pqrst.me_1                     2  5  7  8
pqrst.me_2                     2  5  7  8
```

This assumes the numbers are never higher than 9.  It would be only slightly more code to separate all trailing digits.

Comment: Why partition with a dummy variable instead of `.split(, maxsplit=1)`?

Comment: Either way.  Intuitively, I suspect the partition is slightly quicker, because a simpler routine is usually faster than a more complicated one, but the difference is ignorable.

Comment: Thanks Tim! The following version worked for me:
`name,vals == line.rstrip().split(' ',1)
prefix,suffix = name.split('ABC_')
for rest in suffix.split('_X_'):
print(prefix + rest[:None], val)`

Comment: You said you wanted `hi1` to become `hi_1`.  Your code does not do that.  And, BTW, `rest[:None]` is the same as `rest`.